# FFmpeg losses conversion of video files

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have some MP4 file that shares a problem: VLC player takes a long time to load them, like 30s. I found I can resolve this issue by using the following command to convert them:

`ffmpeg -i (input file name, MP4 file) -vcodec copy -acodec copy (output file name, MP4 file)`

The output file is slightly larger than the input one. I guess FFmpeg generate some head information for it.
My question is whether such an operation is lossless or lossy. Does FFmpeg re-compression my video file?
Thanks

Comment: That process won't recompress the video and audio.

Answer (score 0):

There are some streaming/low latency optimizations which can be done (moving index at the beginning of file and using of fragmentation). These aren't (usually :) ) needed when using player (or editor) off-line. It seems like these optimizations are ffmpeg's default.
You only copied and reordered the streams, without any other reprocessing.